# Using template parameter vs constructor argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

If i have for example some template struct, and i want to give it a user-defined size for some member i can do it by passing a value to constructor like so:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    int m_size;

    Foo(int u_size)
        :
        m_size {u_size}
    {
    }
};
```

and i can also do it by having a non-type template parameter (kinda the way `std::array` does it), like so:

```cpp
template <typename T, int u_size>
struct Foo {
    int m_size;

    Foo()
        :
        m_size {u_size}
    {
    }
};
```

My question is, what is the difference between these two methods, and when is it useful to use either of them?

Comment: For the non-type template parameter version it generally doesn't make sense to have another member variable. One would just use `u_size` for everything inside the class.

Comment: `std::array` **needs** its `size` to be known at compile time, it wouldn't work otherwise as it has something like `T data[size];` as data member. So if it works for you with an constructor argument, that is probably (i.e. in most situations) the way to go.

Comment: @paleonix the member is not `const`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, but having `m_size` and `u_size` differ at runtime seems like a bad idea. Having a `const` member is a very bad idea as well. And yes, one can probably find some weird use-case were these would be sensible things to do, but it would be exceedingly rare.

Comment: "yes, but having m_size and u_size differ at runtime seems like a bad" why? You can have a vector with initial size 2 and later you resize it to 42. This is not an example where you would make `2` a template parameter, but you cannot exclude that there is one where it would make sense

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "it is questionable to require an instance that uses 42 as initial value and an instance that uses 24 as initial value to be of different types." We are agreeing...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number My point is just that in most cases where both are an option (i.e. one **does not have to use** a template parameter), using one is comparable to premature optimization. But this was just a hint and therefore a comment, not an answer, which should go more into detail about this kind of thing.

Comment: @paleonix frankly I dont see the relation to premature optimization. I prefer to make decisions at compile time when I can. I do this not for more performance, but for cleaner design. Btw I found a good example. `Foo<int,42>` is a skyscraper whose basement has a width of 42. During its lifetime the widht of the top level (`m_size`) can change, but the width of the basement is fixed (`u_size`). Even with this example, I see it in the realm of design rather than optimization to choose between A) skyscrapers with different basement width are of different type or B) of same type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251495/discussion-between-paleonix-and-463035818-is-not-a-number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `u_size` to determine the initializer for the member `m_size`. The difference between the two examples boils down to `Foo<T,i>` being a different type than `Foo<T,j>`. Other than being instantiations of the same template (which usually does not mean much) they are totally unrelated. On the other hand, in the first case, any `Foo<T>` is of the same type `Foo<T>`, no matter what was the initial value for the member.

If `m_size` changes at runtime, it is questionable to require an instance that uses `42` as initial value and an instance that uses `24` as initial value to be of different types.

Maybe `m_size` does not change at runtime, then it can make sense to have the initial value as part of the type (like eg with `std::array`). Maybe it does change at runtime, but nevertheless there are reasons to have the initial value baked into the type. There is no "better" Or "worse", it depends what you want/need.

Comment: There are even types which have fixed value or a magic value to say the value is dynamic (as [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).